# How to determine which stylesheet rules are applied

Tags: css, stylesheet

I've inherited code where a web page references several stylesheets.  Within the code, there is a div class reference to "container".  But "container" exists within several of the referenced stylesheets.  How can I determine which one it is referencing?  Thank you.

Comment: All of them....

Comment: Yoi think like read a books meaning whole properties collected as reading order for example margin-top when browser see margintop:5px applied this properties on rendering time then if see other definition after first definition margintop:10px then applied last properties. End of the reead whole css document your object has collected properties and each prop rendered but except !important definition, if browser see important then doesnt apply after that.

Comment: All of them should be applied, however if you have a look at the order of your style sheets as they're imported, i.e. the <link rel='stylesheet'...> etc order, the last stylesheet imported is the most prevalent.. What I mean by this is, if you have 2 classes called container, and they both set the css property 'display', but one sets it to 'display:none' and the other 'display:block', the LAST imported stylesheet will apply the property. Hopefully my ramblings make some sense there.

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using?

Both Firefox and Chrome have excellent developer tools built in that allow you to inspect the DOM of your page and determine what styling rules are applied to each element and in what order, including what files they are located in.

For example, in Chrome, start by right-clicking on an element on the page and then chose "Inspect" from the menu. You will see in the **Styles** section what rules were applied and from which files. (see: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/)

Comment: I would think I'd be able to see within my IDE (Visual Studio).  But I'll check out the DOM thanks.